# Flutter - Always getting wrong POST 400 response before getting the expected 200

Tags: asynchronous, flutter, dart, http-post

I'm having some trouble trying to get the correct response to a POST request in Flutter. This is the method I have written:

```
  Future<void> processUnload(String code) async {
    Map info = {
      'code': "$code",
    };

    try {
      var response = await http.post(
        url + "/unload/code",
        body: json.encode(info), headers: {
          "Content-Type": "application/json",
          "Authorization": "Bearer $token"
        }
      );

      if (response.statusCode == 200) {
        showUnloadOKMessage();
      } else {
        showUnloadNotOKMessage(response.body);
      }

    }catch (error) {

      if (error.toString().contains("Failed host lookup")) {
        notDelivered.add(OfflineCart(code, DateTime.now().toString()));
        showOfflineUnloadMessage();
      }

    }    
  }

  showUnloadOKMessage() {    
    return showDialog<void>(
      context: context,
      barrierDismissible: false,
      builder: (BuildContext context) {
        return AlertDialog(
          title:
              Text('Unload OK.', style: TextStyle(color: Colors.green)),
          actions: <Widget>[
            FlatButton(
              child: Text('OK', style: botonGrandeRojo),
              onPressed: () {
                Navigator.of(context).pop();
                FocusScope.of(contextobuild).requestFocus(focusNode);
              },
            ),
          ],
        );
      },
    );
  }

  showUnloadNotOKMessage(String msg) {
    return showDialog<void>(
      context: context,
      barrierDismissible: false,
      builder: (BuildContext context) {
        return AlertDialog(
          title: Text(msg, style: TextStyle(color: Colors.red)),
          actions: <Widget>[
            FlatButton(
              child: Text('OK', style: botonGrandeRojo),
              onPressed: () {
                Navigator.of(context).pop();
                FocusScope.of(contextobuild).requestFocus(focusNode);
              },
            ),
          ],
        );
      },
    );
  }
```

The problem is that, when the POST request is made, I ALWAYS get 4 or 5 response.statusCode == 400 before getting the actual and expected response.statusCode == 200. Thus, the app always displays 4 or 5 "Not OK messages" before displaying the expected "Unload OK" one.

I've read quite a few async/await/then articles ([Threading in Flutter](https://medium.com/flutter-community/futures-async-await-threading-in-flutter-baeeab1c1fe3), [Using Futures Guide for Beginners](https://medium.com/flutter-community/a-guide-to-using-futures-in-flutter-for-beginners-ebeddfbfb967), [Flutter Async Loader](https://medium.com/flutter-community/flutter-plugins-asyncloader-6efd9d19b6a3)), and I'm pretty sure the problem is the way I've written the code, but I can't get it to work properly, since I don't have any experience working with asynchronous calls.

Thank you.

Comment: what url are you posting? does it behave them same with `curl`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the bug. The problem was that the processUnload method was being called multiple times within a setState(). So, I just had to add a flag to prevent it to be called more than once at the same time and remove the setState():

```
  Widget createCodeText() {
    bool processing = false;

    return Expanded(
      child: TextField(
        autofocus: true,
        decoration: InputDecoration(hintText: 'Esperando lectura...'),
        showCursor: false,
        controller: controllerCode,
        focusNode: focusNode,

        onChanged: (code) async {
          if (!processing){
            processing = true;
            await processUnload (code);
            processing = false;
            controllerCode.clear();
          }
        },

      ),
    );
  }
```